# Have an optional field in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 Oracle databases, one with the User Scheme (id, username, password) and the second one with (id, username, password, email).

My Sequelize model look like this :

```
const User = database.define('Users', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
},{
    tableName: 'Users',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false
});
```

How can I declare my email field as "optional" so I can push to the both databases ?

PS: I'm in JS and no TS

Comment: If you have two database, then why not just have two schemas? where you declare the first schema as one without email, and then the other as `{ ...withoutEmail, email: { ... }}`. You don't want "optional" columns, because that's now how your database schemas work. You want rigidly correct schema mapping, specific to the database(s) you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon how you have set up the database configuration, you have to add the schema fields conditionally.

You would have to do something similar to the following:

`

```
const schemaFields = {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
 }

//Add your logic here
if(second database logic){
    schemaFields.email = {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
}

const User = database.define('Users', schemaFields, {
    tableName: 'Users',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false
});
```

`